# Ubuntu: Multiple interfaces, one lan only

Tags: ubuntu, local-area-network, gateway, ifconfig, wlan

I have 2 interfaces:

- wlan0: Connected to normal network with DHCP (has internet)
- eth0: Connected to LAN only. Used for PXE boot and NFS

The network-manager service is not installed on this machine.

If I leave /etc/network/interfaces totally blank, both interfaces come up OK but each has a default gateway set. I run `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.10.100 metric 202
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.0.20 metric 303
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.20 metric 303
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.100 metric 202
```

The default route on 192.168.10.1 is in the way of internet connectivity. If I run `sudo route del default` and the `ip route` again:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.0.20 metric 303
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.20 metric 303
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.100 metric 202
```

Everything is good:

```
adam@sheep:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.5.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iad30s07-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.5.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=38.3 ms
64 bytes from iad30s07-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.5.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=38.7 ms
```

If I put anything at all in /etc/network/interfaces, wlan0 will not come up and the machine hangs at this boot step for about a minute: `a start job is running for Raise network interfaces`. Even this fails:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

1. Am I missing something? Have I configured something incorrectly?
2. How do I get that default route on eth0 to never be set in the first place?

I get the feeling the end solution looks something like this:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
up route del default
```

but I'm currently stuck because even a more basic config fails.

Comment: You need to fix this in the router, not in the host.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? I assume you're talking about the PXE server (which is serving DHCP that eth0 is connected to, but it's not clear from your comment.

Comment: Your wired network has some DHCP server which is assigning a gateway address, and should not be.

Comment: Got it. I'll look into changing that.

Comment: That's it! I had to convince my dnsmasq dhcp server to stop sending out gateway and dns addresses.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the dnsmasq configuration on the PXE server. It was sending out a gateway address so even when that address was removed from a client, it would eventually be resent as the client got a new DHCP lease. The permanent fix suggested by Michael Hampton is to stop the DHCP server from suggesting a gateway.

I had

```
# DHCP server for PXE
interface=eno1
dhcp-range=192.168.10.50,192.168.10.150,12h
dhcp-option=66,192.168.10.1 #option 66 sets the address of the TFTP server
```

but needed to *explicitly disable* the gateway address from being sent:

```
interface=eno1
dhcp-range=192.168.10.50,192.168.10.150,12h
dhcp-option=66,192.168.10.1 # option 66 sets the address of the TFTP server
dhcp-option=3
dhcp-option=6
```

This sets the gateway (option 3) and dns (option 6) to nil